# How to use functions defined in a C++-produced .dll or .lib file within Lazarus (freepascal)?

Tags: c++, dll, freepascal, lazarus

I want to use functions from the '[ANN](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/)' library (Approximate Nearest Neighbor) in my Lazarus code. This application is written in C++, and comes with source code. How can I access the functions from within Lazarus/FreePascal?

Edit: Lazarus/FPC is similar to Delphi.

Comment: Bump, see updated answer below (QT reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the library. If it is the "C" subset of C++, or if the interface is specially crafted to be interoperable, see opc0de's answer. An important signal that this is the case is an "extern C {}" block.

If the library is *true* C++, you have a problem. There is no universal exporting mechanism for C++, and even two different C++ compilers generally don't understand eachother.

To use it, you must create a so called wrapper. A piece of code compiled with the /same/ C++ compiler that wraps everything C++ specific and only exports plain C functions (extern C{})

As an example, have a look at the so called QTPAS wrapper, that wraps QT for use in Free Pascal/Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import a function from a dll you can do this

```
function ExportedFunctionName(parameters):ResultType;cdecl;external 'library.dll';
```

If is a c++ library use cdecl if is a windows library use stdcall

These represent the parameter passing conventions